# What is the word for mud on road which becomes wet due to rain? / What is keechad called in English?

Tags: word-request

After the heavy rain falls, the mud becomes so wet that it sticks to your feet if you walk over it.

In **Hindi** it is called **Keechad**. What is the word for it in English?

[image]

Comment: Mud was the right word.

Comment: I think you mixed up dirt and mud. Before it gets wet, it's dirt - after it gets wet, it's mud. And after it dries out again, it's usually just dry (or dried out) mud.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd just call it *mud.* If you want to suggest that it is very wet and sticky, [*slime*](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/slime?q=slime) or [*muck*](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/muck_1?q=muck) would also work.

Since *slime* can also refer to other liquids besides mud, you could be even more specific by using the two-word phrase *slimy mud.*

Or if you want to emphasize the stickiness, call it *sticky mud.*

But this seems unnecessary to me because when we describe something as "mud", the default assumption is that it is not only dirty and wet, but also somewhat fluid and slimy. If it is dirty and wet, but solid and not slimy, we'd be more likely to describe it using other words than "mud," like "damp earth" or "wet ground" or "moist soil."

Comment: I'm not very sure, but I think "sodden mud" could work, too. ("Sodden mud" may have more water than "damp mud" in it, imho.)

Answer (score 4):

Mud is indeed the correct word. If you want to be more specific, you need to add more words. For mud that builds up and sticks to your feet, I'd use things like:

> Sticky mud.
>
> Mud that sticks to your feet.
>
> Mud that builds up on your feet.

And in conversation:

> "Seriously, that mud stuck so much that it was like wearing
>   platform shoes!"

(platform shoes are shoes with very thick soles, usually 1 - 4 inches)

Answer (score 1):

"Keechad" translates exactly to **Wet Dirt** or **Mud Slush** or **Muck**

Comment: Dirt may not be the correct word since dirt is used for dirty things? Am I wrong? Often, if there is something dirty on the floor and I don't know what it is , I simply say it is dirt - It may or may not be wet mud.

Comment: In AmE, **dirt** and **slush** have two very different meanings: **dirt** is the earthy stuff on the ground, usually dry; **slush** is wet stuff but usually made from **snow**, which I'm guessing doesn't happen much in India. **Mud** is wet dirt, the stuff that sticks to your feet and shoes, if it gets really deep then it's **knee deep mud**.

Answer (score 0):

Muddy terrain (कीचड़) is not unique to India. I would use "a quagmire" to describe a challenging muddy condition.

Answer (score -1):

There is no comparing word for keechad in English, because there is never any keechad in England.

Comment: Oh believe me, there is plenty of mud in England.